# How do I assign a JSON response from this API I'm using to elements on my page?

Tags: javascript, json, api

I'm trying to use the API from https://developer.forecast.io and I'm getting a JSON response, this is the first time I'm using an API and all I really need to know is, how do I assign the JSON response I get back from their API to elements on my page. Thanks!

[image]

This is done with a script-tag in my header:

script(src='https://api.forecast.io/forecast/APIKEY/LAT,LON')

Comment: Out of curiosity, how are you fetching the JSON? Are you already using a library like jQuery, or just going direct with Javascript using xmlhttprequest?

Comment: @Snixtor simply by putting a <script src="theirapi"> in my header

Answer (score 2):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ you need to add a success callback, at the bottom of that page are examples you can look at.

**EDIT**

ok i saw that you are using a script tag with the request, since the api is outside your current domain you need to make a JSONP request

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.forecast.io/forecast/APIKEY/LAT,LON',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data){
            //do whatever you want with the data here
            $("body").append(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
});
```

off course you need to make some tweaks to that piece of block but you get the idea

Comment: I'm not using AJAX so I don't know where to set the function, see my edit at the bottom of the original post

Comment: you need to use ajax.. what are you using to make that request?.. an iframe?

Comment: Using Ajax I get XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.forecast.io/forecast/b28/56.7272,-111.3803. Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: you need to use jsonp.. you get that error because you cant make cross origin ajax without CORS

Comment: The docs for the API *do* mention the use of the `callback` option for JSONP calls - https://developer.forecast.io/docs/v2 So good news there is that it's supported. As they point out though, doing that would mean publicly exposing your API key, which may not be a wise move.

Comment: off course, the other solution is to use a sort of proxy in your backend to retrieve this data for you.. the only possibilities from the frontend are 1. JSON - 2. CORS

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is DOM manipulation. DOM is the HTML [Document Object Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), an object representation of the HTML comprising a document. There are a *lot* of ways to go about this, but one of the more popular Javascript libraries for performing this task is jQuery. See their help documentation category on [manipulation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) for more information.

OK, based on your clarification, you're not yet using AJAX. I say "not yet", because you're going to need to. Again, I'll recommend jQuery for that, and their own documentation as the best resource. For a simple "get", your easiest option is the [getJSON method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

So, at a very simple level you might do something like:

```
$(function(){
    $.getJSON('url_to_api', function(data) {
        $("#SummaryBox").append("<div>" + data.hourly.summary + "</div>");
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not using AJAX so I don't know where to set the function, see my edit at the bottom of the original post

Comment: Rather than a script tag that references the api url directly, make it reference your own local javascript file, and inside that file put some code like Snixtor suggested.

Comment: @Snixtor @KevinCollins I get `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.forecast.io/forecast/b28/56.7272,-111.3803. Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. `

Comment: You'll need to use JSONP by providing the name of a callback function. For details, look under the Options heading in their docs (https://developer.forecast.io/docs/v2).